# Reuse wildcard value in Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm checking the `onUpdate` of a `{postId}`, and I want to run a firebase database call with that same `{postId}`.. if that makes sense. Here is my code:

```
exports.handleVoteKarma = functions.database
.ref('upvotes/{postId}')
.onUpdate(async change => {
    const scoreBefore = change.before.val() || 0;
    const scoreAfter = change.after.val();
    //This {postId} should be the same as the one above for the upvotes/{postId}
    adb.ref('{item}/{loc}/{postId}/score').once('value').then((usr) => {

    });
    return null;
});
```

Essentially I want the `{postId}` in `upvotes/` to have the same value as the `{postId}` when I check the `score`.. will it work like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realtime Database triggers accept a second argument, which you're not using in your function:

```
exports.handleVoteKarma = functions.database
.ref('upvotes/{postId}')
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    // note the "context" parameter here
});
```

This is an [EventContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext) object and it contains a [params](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#params) property with the values of the wildcards in the path.  You'd use it simply like this:

```
const postId = context.params.postId
```

You can then use the `postId` string later to build other refs.

There is more discussion in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_database_instance_and_path).

Comment: Thanks this was awesome! Do you maybe know why this call to the db returns null? `adb.ref('{item}/{loc}/'+ postId).once('value').then((usr) => {` am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know - it sounds like you have a second question to ask that explains the new problem you're running into now.

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake. Firebase database calls don't accept wildcards